# Citation at the beginning of a sentence not showing up correctly

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

> (Hudson, 2016) claims that we can improve the social well-being, secondlanguage learning and confidence of an individual using the commercialgames

This is the citation which I need to fix, and it should appear as

> Hudson, (2016) claims that we can improve the social well-being, secondlanguage learning and confidence of an individual using the commercialgames

To achieve this, I tried using the `natbib` package. My bibilography is as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{30}
\bibitem[Ferris, 1994]{R13}
Ferris, D. R. (1994). Lexical and syntactic features of ESL writing by students at different levels of L2 proficiency. \textit{Tesol Quarterly, 28}(2), 414-420.
\end{thebibliography}
```

With the `natbib`, in my generated pdf, the citation shows up as just the number 13, instead of as (Ferris, 1990). I've tried using `cite`, `citep`, `citet`, none of them works. Please help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the `\bibitem` should be different:

```
\bibitem[Ferris(1994)]{R13}
Ferris, D. R. (1994). Lexical and syntactic features of ESL writing by students at
  different levels of L2 proficiency. \emph{Tesol Quarterly}, 28 (2), 414--420, 1994.
```

With this, the following input along with `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}`

```
\citet{R13} claims that we can improve the social well-being,
second language learning and confidence of an individual using
the commercial games.
```

will print as

[image]

Of course it should be better to use BibTeX, rather than manually inputting the bibliography data.

Comment: It is still showing up as Ferris (13), instead of Ferris (1994). I have just learned using latex, haven't used bibtex before, all the bibitems are manual. There should be someway to fix this as of now?

Comment: This is a really strange behaviour. My `thebibliography` has 30 `bibitems`. If I remove everything except R13, then it shows up fine in the output.

Comment: @vipin8169 Did you look carefully at the format of the optional argument to `\bibitem`?

Comment: yes, with my existing format it works when i remove all the other bibitems.

Comment: Anyways I switched to using bibtex